# SQL query to identify paired items (challenging)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Assume there is a relation database with one table:

```
{datetime, tapeID, backupStatus}

2012-07-09 3:00, ID33, Start
2012-07-09 3:05, ID34, Start
2012-07-09 3:10, ID35, Start
2012-07-09 4:05, ID34, End
2012-07-09 4:10, ID33, Start
2012-07-09 5:05, ID33, End
2012-07-09 5:10, ID34, Start
2012-07-09 6:00, ID34, End
2012-07-10 4:00, ID35, Start
2012-07-11 5:00, ID35, End
```

tapeID = any of 100 different tapes each with their own unique ID.

backupStatus = one of two assignments either Start or End.

I want to write a SQL query that returns five fields

```
{startTime,endTime,tapeID,totalBackupDuration,numberOfRestarts}
2012-07-09 3:00,2012-07-09 5:05, ID33, 0days2hours5min,1
2012-07-09 3:05,2012-07-09 4:05, ID34, 0days1hours0min,0
2012-07-09 3:10,2012-07-10 5:00, ID35, 0days0hours50min,1
2012-07-09 5:10,2012-07-09 6:00, ID34, 0days0hours50min,0
```

I'm looking to pair the start and end dates to identify when each backupset has truely completed.  The caveat here is that the backup of a single backupset may be restarted so there may be multiple Start times that are not considered complete until the following End event.  A single backupset may be backed up multiple times a day, which would need to be identified as a with a separate start and end time.

Thank you for your assistance in advance!
B

Comment: @Mike notice the updates! P.S. It wasn't SO challenging as all that. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my version. If you add `INSERT #T SELECT '2012-07-11 12:00', 'ID35', 'Start'` to the table, you'll see unfinished backups in this query as well. `OUTER APPLY` is a natural way to solve the problem.

```
SELECT
   Min(T.dt) StartTime,
   Max(E.dt) EndTime,
   T.tapeID,
   Datediff(Minute, Min(T.dt), Max(E.dt)) TotalBackupDuration,
   Count(*) - 1 NumberOfRestarts
FROM
   #T T
   OUTER APPLY (
      SELECT TOP 1 E.dt
      FROM #T E
      WHERE
         T.tapeID = E.tapeID
         AND E.BackupStatus = 'End'
         AND E.dt > T.dt
      ORDER BY E.dt
   ) E
WHERE
   T.BackupStatus = 'Start'
GROUP BY
   T.tapeID,
   IsNull(E.dt, T.dt)
```

One thing about CROSS APPLY is that if you're only returning one row and the outer references are all real tables, you have an equivalent in SQL 2000 by moving it into the WHERE clause of a derived table:

```
SELECT
   Min(T.dt) StartTime,
   Max(T.EndTime) EndTime,
   T.tapeID,
   Datediff(Minute, Min(T.dt), Max(T.EndTime)) TotalBackupDuration,
   Count(*) - 1 NumberOfRestarts
FROM (
      SELECT
         T.*,
         (SELECT TOP 1 E.dt
            FROM #T E
            WHERE
               T.tapeID = E.tapeID
               AND E.BackupStatus = 'End'
               AND E.dt > T.dt
            ORDER BY E.dt
         ) EndTime
      FROM #T T
      WHERE T.BackupStatus = 'Start'
   ) T
GROUP BY
   T.tapeID,
   IsNull(T.EndTime, T.dt)
```

For outer references that are not all real tables (you want a calculated value from another subquery's outer reference) you have to add nested derived tables to accomplish this.

I finally bit the bullet and did some real testing. I used SPFiredrake's table population script to see the actual performance with a large amount of data. I did it programmatically so there are no typing errors. I took 10 executions each, and threw out the worst and best value for each column, then averaged the remaining 8 column values for that statistic.

The indexes were created after populating the table, with 100% fill factor. The Indexes column shows 1 when just the clustered index is present. It shows 2 when the nonclustered index on BackupStatus is added.

To exclude client network data transfer from the testing, I selected each query into variables like so:

```
DECLARE
   @StartTime datetime,
   @EndTime datetime,
   @TapeID varchar(5),
   @Duration int,
   @Restarts int;


WITH A AS (
-- The query here
)
SELECT
   @StartTime = StartTime,
   @EndTime = EndTime,
   @TapeID = TapeID,
   @Duration = TotalBackupDuration,
   @Restarts = NumberOfRestarts
FROM A;
```

I also trimmed the table column lengths to something more reasonable: tapeID varchar(5), BackupStatus varchar(5). In fact, the BackupStatus should be a bit column, and the tapeID should be an integer. But we'll stick with varchar for the time being.

```
   Server  Indexes       UserName   Reads  Writes    CPU  Duration
---------  -------  -------------  ------  ------  -----  --------
   x86 VM        1          ErikE   97219       0    599       325
   x86 VM        1  Gordon Linoff     606       0  63980     54638
   x86 VM        1    SPFiredrake  344927     260  23621     13105

   x86 VM        2          ErikE   96388       0    579       324
   x86 VM        2  Gordon Linoff  251443       0  22775     11830
   x86 VM        2    SPFiredrake  197845       0  11602      5986

x64 Beefy        1          ErikE   96745       0    919        61
x64 Beefy        1  Gordon Linoff  320012      70  62372     13400
x64 Beefy        1    SPFiredrake  362545     288  20154      1686

x64 Beefy        2          ErikE   96545       0    685       164
x64 Beefy        2  Gordon Linoff  343952      72  65092     17391
x64 Beefy        2    SPFiredrake  198288       0  10477       924
```

Notes:

- x86 VM: an almost idle virtual machine, Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (RTM) - 10.0.1600.22 (Intel X86)
- x64 Beefy: a quite beefy and possibly very busy Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1765.0 (X64)

The second index helped all the queries, mine the least.

It is interesting that Gordon's initially low number of reads on one server was high on the second--but it had a lower duration, so it obviously picked a different execution plan probably due to having more resources to search the possible plan space faster (being a beefier server). But, the index raised the number of reads because that plan lowered the CPU cost by a ton and so costed out less in the optimizer.

Comment: Very nice. I was trying to bypass the need for grouping so it would be speedier. Yours is the simplest of the solutions, but also the slowest. According to execution plan in SSMS (running all three in succession), my solution uses 8% of the batch, Gordon's takes 23%, and yours takes 69%. Then again I was also assuming it was ordered to begin with (bad assumption). Adding `order by dt` in my outer apply changes to 32/17/50. Adding indexes (Clustered: tapeID, dt; Index BackupStatus) changed it to 22/39/39. Moral of the story? Make sure your table is properly indexed...

Comment: @SPFiredrake I looked at the execution plans too--but the problem is that they aren't always accurate. The table has too little data to do real I/O testing. I don't have time now, but would you be willing to write a script to generate a few hundred thousand rows of data so we can test actual IO and CPU? And yes... indexes are going to change things a lot!

Comment: Script generated, you can alter the parameters to suit your liking. If you want to do a full 24 hours, then you'll have to modify some of the script (getting rid of forcing the End to come after first Start of the day, for example), but I'm sure you can find your way around. https://gist.github.com/3091448

Comment: Are you sure you used my most recent code? Your numbers aren't matching mine up at all (not even by a long shot). Also, clearing the buffers is a poor statistical measure, because 95% of the time (in production) it will be hit frequently enough that most of the records will be cached. All of my tests were performed on production servers that are already taking a beating, so I'm curious about what could cause such a disparity between our results. Then again, I was also working with a temp table instead of regular table, so that could be why...

Comment: @ErikE . . . this is quite impressive.  In general, I try to keep my queries as close to standard SQL as possible, while avoiding correlated subqueries (which is usually possible) and nested selects (in some databases, these result in nested loop joins).  However, you give a very good analysis on how different query structures are useful, at least in SQL Server.  The sad thing is, SQL is a declarative language, so this is a failure of the SQL engine to optimize the queries properly.

Comment: @SPFiredrake I'll try to rerun my tests later. I copied the queries directly from the answers. Strange!

Comment: @GordonLinoff I believe in using the full expressive power of the database engine I'm using, rather than trying to use standard SQL. I am experienced enough that when the engine dictates I use a smaller set I can still accomplish pretty much anything. See my new comment on your post.

Comment: @Erike, I'm neither going to apologize for my style nor for the failure of sql engines to optimize code.  On the other hand, I applaud the folks who are experts in particular database engines and know how to get performance out of them.

Comment: @Gordon No apology necessary! You are obviously an accomplished SQL writer. Take or leave my critical constructiveness. :)

Comment: @SPFiredrake I did mislead you, but not intentionally! I created the index AFTER filling the table, because with 90% fill factor there were going to be a lot of page splits due to the random order of inserts. However, in a real-life table, the inserts will be sequential per tape and have many, many fewer page splits. I also changed the fill factor to 100%. So note that the index was created after the data, in my tests. In what way did your data differ?

Comment: @ErikE On my tests the index was created before adding the data (since in production that would the case). If you look at my post, you'll see the kind of timings I was getting, and since this is a table that will probably be hit more frequently than not, most of the pages should be cached. I set fill factor to 90 because that's what I usually set as a default (I'd be curious how changing to 100 would alter things). Either way, after adding an index, the table should be rebuilt to fix the page splits. Either way, it really doesn't matter, because our environments will differ from Mike Jones's.

Comment: @spfiredrake in prod each tape will have its rows entered chronologically, reducing page splits.

Comment: @SPFiredrake I updated the stats from a fresh new run. I am willing to play with putting the indexes on first, but I think it's worth coming up with a deterministic script that will insert the backups in chronological order--this will let us all test the same data, and will reproduce the actual data patterns that will be in use (unlike the random insertions). I won't put that on you, but will try to do it myself some time soon.

Comment: @ErikE Updated. Give it a try now.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is to assign the next end date to all starts.  Then count the number of starts in-between.

```
select tstart.datetime as starttime, min(tend.datetime) as endtime, tstart.tapeid
from (select *
      from t
      where BackupStatus = 'Start'
     ) tstart join
     (select *
      from t
      where BackupStatus = 'End'
     ) tend
     on tstart.tapeid = tend.tapeid and
        tend.datetime >= tstart.datetime
```

This is close, but we have multiple rows for each end time (depending on the number of starts).  To handle this, we need to group by the tapeid and the end time:

```
select min(a.starttime) as starttime, a.endtime, a.tapeid,
       datediff(s, min(a.starttime), endtime), -- NOT CORRECT, DATABASE SPECIFIC
       count(*) - 1 as NumRestarts
from (select tstart.dt as starttime, min(tend.dt) as endtime, tstart.tapeid 
      from (select *
            from #t
            where BackupStatus = 'Start'
           ) tstart join
           (select *
            from #t
            where BackupStatus = 'End'
           ) tend
           on tstart.tapeid = tend.tapeid and
              tend.dt >= tstart.dt
     group by tstart.dt, tstart.tapeid
    ) a
group by a.endtime, a.tapeid
```

I've written this version using SQL Server syntax.  To create the test table, you can use:

```
create table #t (
    dt datetime,
    tapeID varchar(255),
    BackupStatus varchar(255)
)

insert into #t (dt, tapeID, BackupStatus) values ('2012-07-09 3:00', 'ID33', 'Start')
insert into #t (dt, tapeID, BackupStatus) values ('2012-07-09 3:05', 'ID34', 'Start')
insert into #t (dt, tapeID, BackupStatus) values ('2012-07-09 3:10', 'ID35', 'Start')
insert into #t (dt, tapeID, BackupStatus) values ('2012-07-09 4:05', 'ID34', 'End')
insert into #t (dt, tapeID, BackupStatus) values ('2012-07-09 4:10', 'ID33', 'Start')
insert into #t (dt, tapeID, BackupStatus) values ('2012-07-09 5:05', 'ID33', 'End')
insert into #t (dt, tapeID, BackupStatus) values ('2012-07-09 5:10', 'ID34', 'Start')
insert into #t (dt, tapeID, BackupStatus) values ('2012-07-09 6:00', 'ID34', 'End')
insert into #t (dt, tapeID, BackupStatus) values ('2012-07-10 4:00', 'ID35', 'Start')
insert into #t (dt, tapeID, BackupStatus) values ('2012-07-11 5:00', 'ID35', 'End')
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon for your response.  I think we're heading in the right direction.  I made a small adjustment to the query to get start and end date.  Other than that, it seems like the query results are not giving me the start time that I expected for ID34.

Comment: How are the results wrong?  It should be returning two rows for ID34, one for each end time.

Comment: It seems like the query results are not giving me the start time that I expected for ID34.  I modified the times in the initial table to have each record unique. 
    2012-07-09 03:05,2012-07-09 04:05,ID34,1 
    2012-07-09 03:00,2012-07-09 05:05,ID33,2 
    2012-07-09 03:05,2012-07-09 06:00,ID34,2 
    2012-07-09 03:10,2012-07-11 05:00,ID35,2 Notice that ID34 has the same start time for both records. I was hoping that the first record for ID34 would have the 3:05 time as the starttime and the second record for ID34 would have a 5:10 starttime.

Comment: The version of the query that I had was, let me say, "right in spirit".  But not quite right in practice -- somehow, parts of the query got mixed up.  I've fixed the query and tested it.

Comment: Thanks so much Gordon.  I'm pretty new to sql queries and your guidance has accomplished everything I hoped for.  You da man!

Comment: Please explain.  According to the rules explained, it gives the correct answer of starting at 2012-07-09 03:10:00.000, ending at 2012-07-11 05:00:00.000, and having 1 retry, according to the data.  I think the version in the answer is incorrect, since there is no end time at 4 in the data.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Your ID33 record only shows 3300 second difference (which is time from last Start time to End time for a backup). You're very close, and changing `datediff(s, max(a.starttime)...` to `datediff(s, min(a.starttime)...` fixes the problem, as he wants the time from the first start time to completion.

Comment: @GordonLinoff please use tags or people won't know you responded unless they remember to come back! Consider the example output row desired, `2012-07-09 3:00,2012-07-09 5:05, ID33, 0days2hours5min,1` this clearly shows the TotalBackupDuration should count from the first Start, not from the most recent one.

Comment: @SPFireddrake . . . That was my fault. I had in mind that he wanted the duration of the last successful attempt, rather than the overall duration from the first one (which is what I would typically want in this situation).  And ErikE, thank you for the hint about the name.

Comment: @GordonLinoff This page has matured a bit since the last time you probably visited... take a look!

Comment: I've seen your code a couple of times now and you show a distinct style difference from others. For one thing, I've noticed that you tend to think in steps of pieces that then get joined together. This is not bad as it usually makes no difference to the meaning of the query, but you miss query simplification opportunities such as the most inner subqueries in your query above--just put two WHERE conditions and get rid of the derived tables! This is also not the first time that your "standard SQL" suffered a lot in terms of performance (based on at least 1 other question recently).

Answer (score 1):

Thought I'd take a stab at it. Tested out Gordon Linoff's solution, and it doesn't quite calculate correctly for tapeID 33 in his own example (matches to the next start, not the corresponding end).

My attempt assumes you're using SQL server 2005+, as it utilizes CROSS/OUTER APPLY. If you need it for server 2000 I could probably swing it, but this seemed like the cleanest solution to me (as you're starting with all end elements and matching the first start elements to get the result). I'll annotate as well so you can understand what I'm doing.

```
SELECT 
    startTime, endT.dt endTime, endT.tapeID, DATEDIFF(s, startTime, endT.dt), restarts
FROM 
    #t endT -- Main source, getting all 'End' records so we can match.
    OUTER APPLY ( -- Match possible previous 'End' records for the tapeID
        SELECT TOP 1 dt 
        FROM #t 
        WHERE dt < endT.dt AND tapeID = endT.tapeID 
        AND BackupStatus = 'End') g
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT ISNULL(g.dt, CAST(0 AS DATETIME)) dt) t 
    CROSS APPLY ( 
        -- Match 'Start' records between our 'End' record
        -- and our possible previous 'End' record.
        SELECT MIN(dt) startTime, 
            COUNT(*) - 1 restarts -- Restarts, so -1 for the first 'Start'
        FROM #t 
        WHERE tapeID = endT.tapeID AND BackupStatus = 'Start' 
                -- This is where our previous possible 'End' record is considered
            AND dt > t.dt AND dt < endt.dt) starts
WHERE 
    endT.BackupStatus = 'End'
```

Edit: Test data generation script [found at this link.](https://gist.github.com/3091448)

So decided to run some data against the three methods, and found that ErikE's solution is fastest, mine is a VERY close second, and Gordon's is just inefficient for any sizable set (even when working with 1000 records, it started showing slowness). For smaller sets (at about 5k records), my method wins over Erik's, but not by much. Honestly, I like my method as it doesn't require any additional aggregate functions to get the data, but ErikE's wins in the efficiency/speed battle.

Edit 2: For 55k records in the table (and 12k matching start/end pairs), Erik's takes ~0.307s and mine takes ~0.157s (averaging over 50 attempts). I was a little surprised about this, because I would've assumed that individual runs would've translated to the overall, but I guess the index cache is being better utilized by my query so subsequent hits are less expensive. Looking at the execution plans, ErikE's only has 1 branch off the main path, so he's ultimately working with a larger set for most of the query. I have 3 branches that combine closer to the output, so I'm churning on less data at any given moment and combine right at the end.

Comment: Whoops, you are correct. That was an artifact from some testing I was doing. Fixed.

Comment: You are a good man (or woman)! Thank you for stepping up to the challenge and producing the test script. I had a feeling that the aggregate with an index would perform well. I also couldn't duplicate your code. Oh... one more thing: my code includes backups that don't have an end. So it is doing a tiny bit more work.

Answer (score 0):

Make it very simple --
Make one sub query for start event and another one for End event.  Rank function in each set for each row that has start and end.  Then, use a left joins for 2 sub queries:

```
-- QUERY
WITH CTE as 
(
SELECT  dt
        , ID
        , status  
        --, RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DT) as rnk1
        --,  RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY status ORDER BY DT) as rnk2
FROM INT_backup
)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE 
ORDER BY id, rnk2


select * FROM INT_backup order by id, dt

SELECT * 
FROM 
(
    SELECT  dt
            , ID
            , status  
            , rank () over (PARTITION by ID ORDER BY dt) as rnk
    FROM INT_backup
    WHERE status = 'start' 
) START_SET
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT  dt
            , ID
            , status  
            , rank () over (PARTITION by ID ORDER BY dt) as rnk
    FROM INT_backup
    where status = 'END'
) END_SET
ON Start_Set.ID = End_SET.ID 
AND Start_Set.Rnk = End_Set.rnk
```